# IBM java/IBM JVM 1.4.2 certificate expired, can I update it without server?

Tags: java, jvm, websphere

I think I may have met an "IBM java 1.4.2 certificate expired" issue.

The app, which calls IBM java 1.4.2, and then connects the server, throws the error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_expired.
```

In the client, I into `/usr/java142/lib/security/`.

I use `keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts` to check the `cacerts` file.

But I do not know how to update this `cacerts`? Or is there any way I can update it?

For the server, it is a black box, which I have no rights into it.

Comment: February 2002. That software is old enough to vote. And is totally unsupported at this time.

Comment: I think replacing it with the cacerts of a recent Java version might work, though I'm not sure if the file format changed between then and now.

Comment: There is not enough context in the question to understand if the issue is on the server side or a custom keystone in the application.